# How to assertequal for URL and a text of the URL

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse, testng.xml, testng-annotation-test

I login into - https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login
Username : Admin
Password : admin123

once i login ,i land on the Dashboard page
the dashboard page URL is - https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/dashboard/index

now i want to compare actual and expected using Assert

actual URL =https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/dashboard/index
expected = if the actual url contain dashboard word,then pass it else fail.

CAN SOME PLEASE HELP ME , I AM NEW

**MY CODE**

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                
        // LOGIN THE ORANGE HR 
        driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Admin");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("admin123");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='oxd-button oxd-button--medium oxd-button--
                main orangehrm-login-button']")).click();            
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            String URL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            boolean ExpectedURL = URL.contains("dashboard");
             Assert.assertTrue(ExpectedURL, URL);`
```

actual URL =https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/dashboard/index
expected = if the actual url contain dashboard word,then pass it else fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use String.contains() method, as the WebDriver.getCurrentUrl() method returns a String:

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().toLowerCase().contains("dashboard"), "Current page URL is unexpected");
```